# Unable to connect Cloud Function to Cloud SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to set up a Cloud Function to access a Cloud SQL Postgres database.

I'm following this tutorial, but nothing works.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#public-ip-default_1

I don't know how can I set up the Cloud Function Service Account Password. Everything else seems to be enabled and with the correct names and with the correct environment variables.

The Cloud SQL is set up with Public IP.

I tried to see the complete code here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/main.py without success, the connection is refuse every time.

The error points here:

```
unix_socket = "{}/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(
            db_socket_dir,  # e.g. "/cloudsql"
            cloud_sql_connection_name)  # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"

print(unix_socket)
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(

# Equivalent URL:
# postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
#                         ?unix_sock=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
    drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
    username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
    password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
    database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
    query={
        "unix_sock": unix_socket
    }
),
**db_config
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 149, in view_func function(data, context) 
File "/workspace/main.py", line 137, in execute_alert db = init_connection_engine() 
File "/workspace/main.py", line 45, in init_connection_engine return init_unix_connection_engine(db_config) 
File "/workspace/main.py", line 96, in init_unix_connection_engine pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine( 
File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
```

I have tried everything.

UPDATE:

I was able to connect using the private IP and an user with password.
I was missing a configuration in Cloud SQL that allows traffic from subnetworks in the VPC.
Howerver, I'm not able to connect using IAM Service Acount.

Comment: What do you mean by "Cloud Function Service Account Password"? In addition, can you show how did you deploy your cloud function? or share the result of the command `gcloud functions describe <name>`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the guide ask me to create a servise account, give it the permissions to accesses Cloud SQL and attach it to the Cloud Function. The code ask for an db_pass but I can't add it to the Service Account.

Comment: Ok, the db_pass isn't attached to the service account, you need to use it in your code to connect to the database. The Service account  need only the SQL permission (Cloud SQL client role) and deployed with your Cloud Functions

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so, can I remove db_pass from this code?

Comment: Yes, with postgres, if you use the [cloud IAM authentication flag](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authentication#instance_configuration_for) and the correct service account database access

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I enabled the flag but I'm geting "in handle_AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST raise InterfaceError( pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError: server requesting password authentication, but no password was provided"

Comment: @ThadeuAntonioFerreiraMelo Would you kindly specify how did you manage to finally connect using user/password? Thanks!